# Visual editor IDEA for JSP

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

Have an IDEA any visual editor for jsp/jsf like an Eclipse?
[image: http://www.myeclipseide.com/modules/ContentExpress/img_repository/docs/validate_code_complete_annot.gif]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but there is an idea for such editor in [wishlist](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/wishlist/show?pr=&wid=37) on their site. You can vote for it.